# Use of datetime timedelta with numpy 3d array

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, datetime, timedelta

I have a 3D array with the count of number of days past a benchmark date (e.g., 01.01.2000). I am interested in the actual day-of-year (DOY: 1-365/366)rather than the total number of days past a given date.

For a single value, the below syntax works. For e.g.,

```
import numpy as np
import datetime

data = 1595
date = datetime.datetime(2000,1,1,0,0) + datetime.timedelta(data -1)
date.timetuple().tm_yday
134
```

However, I am having issues with using a 3D array.

```
import numpy as np
import datetime

data = np.random.randint(5, size = (2,2,2))
data = data + 1595
data
array([[[1596, 1595],
    [1599, 1599]],

   [[1596, 1599],
    [1595, 1595]]])

#Function
def Int_to_DOY(int_array):
    date_ = datetime.datetime(2000,1,1,0,0) + datetime.timedelta(int_array - 1)
    return date_.timetuple().tm_yday

doy_data = data * 0 #Empty array

for i in range(2):
    doy_data[:, :, i] = Int_to_DOY(data[:, :, i])
```

Here is the error message and I am not able to figure this out.

```
TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: numpy.ndarray
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you add your expected output?

Comment: `array([[[135, 134],
    [138, 138]],

   [[135, 138],
    [134, 134]]])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import datetime

data = np.random.randint(5, size = (2,2,2))
data = data + 1595

#Function
def Int_to_DOY(int_array):
    date_ = datetime.datetime(2000,1,1,0,0) + datetime.timedelta(int(int_array) -1)
    return date_.timetuple().tm_yday

doy_data = data.flatten()

for i in range(len(doy_data)):
    doy_data[i] = Int_to_DOY(doy_data[i])

doy_data = doy_data.reshape((2,2,2))
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution and I believe, I was pushing a 2D array wherein it should have been a vector.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged `pandas`:

```
data = np.array([[[1596, 1595],
    [1599, 1599]],

   [[1596, 1599],
    [1595, 1595]]])

s = pd.to_datetime('2000-01-01') + pd.to_timedelta(data.ravel(), unit='D') 
s.dayofyear.values.reshape(data.shape) - 1
```

Output:

```
array([[[135, 134],
        [138, 138]],

       [[135, 138],
        [134, 134]]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Thank you! I like the pandas approach and something new I learnt today.

Comment: Note: On a larger array, pandas is way faster!